# Use sudo to simulate initial login and run command

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have a [Dev-Install environment](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/install-software-on-base-images) setup on my Chromebook.

Whenever I use it through `crosh`, I immediately switch to the root user using `sudo -i`. The reason that `sudo -i` is used instead of `sudo su` is so the environment variables that enable the use of Dev-Install's things are kept.

After running `sudo -i`, I then run:

```
. ${SOURCE_THIS_FILE}
```

`${SOURCE_THIS_FILE}` is just a placeholder which defines/redefines several aliases, functions, and variables.

Typing out the path to `${SOURCE_THIS_FILE}` is kind of annoying, so I was wondering if there was anyway I could combine `sudo -i` and `. ${SOURCE_THIS_FILE}` such that the latter will be run immediately after switching to root?

I can then put that line in the `.bashrc` that is run by `crosh` so I'd immediately switch to a root shell upon opening the terminal in Chrome.

Comment: you can pass a flag to sudo so that it passes the environment variables.. I believe it's `-e`

Comment: do you want the sourcing to happen *only if* you've run `sudo -i`, or can it happen every time root gets a bash shell?